# Error in MySQL Xampp

Tags: mysql, apache

I have installed MySQL Workbench on my computer that is using port 3306.

I installed Xampp apache server. When I start the services this error appears:

```
Problem detected!
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults- ile="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56"! MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I changed the mysql port for xampp in the following way:

Stop the xampp server, if it is already running.
Edit the value to "port" in xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini
Code:

```
Password = your_password   
port =  3306  --->  3307  
socket =  "/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

and here also

Code:

```
The MySQL server 
[ mysqld ] 
port =  3306  --->  3307 
socket =  "/ xampp / mysql / mysql.sock"
```

And Started mysql service however the error remains.

Does someone can help me solve this please?

thank you all

best regards

----------------------------MySQL_error.log---------------------------

```
140818 12:09:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
140818 12:09:30 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
140818 12:09:30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140818 12:09:30 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140818 12:09:30 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140818 12:09:30 [ERROR] Aborting

140818 12:09:30 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

140818 12:21:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
140818 12:21:45 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
140818 12:21:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140818 12:21:45 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140818 12:21:45 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140818 12:21:45 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: There is also a couple of default MySQL port settings in the \xampp\php\php.ini file thatmay need changing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i tried what you said, but the error remains :(

Comment: I had the same issue and the only thing that would resolve it was a complete un-install & re-install of XAMPP. I also had to make the changes you have already noted. You could try this unless somebody else has a better suggestion, I think you have made all of the obvious changes to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like you got two MySQL servers running at the same time. I suggest you check your process list for a process called `mysqld.exe`. (You can also check the "Netstat" as provided by Control Panel) This should be your already running instance of MySQL Server. End that one however you like and try again.

In your case I'd also consider installing the MySQL server as windows-service. This allows you to "externally" manage the server and make sure you only have one instance running.

You can accomplish that by clicking the red x beside the Modulename and wait for it to turn into a green checkmark.

[image: Control panel with apache and MySQL installed as Service]

After that your Control Panel should looks something like that ▲▲
I installed both MySQL and Apache as service, but that's your preference ;)

You can then configure your MySQL Workbench to access your already running server instead of starting up its own.

You shouldn't be required to change the port of MySQL in any case.

In addition to that, your Apache Module should be able to launch even without MySQL started...